# Does Expression Web produce semantically correct html?

Tags: expression-web

I am usng Expressoin Web to design some pages and wondering if it generates xhtml that is compatible with all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could test it and post your answer here. :-)

> http://validator.w3.org/
>
> http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Not sure how good your German is, but I found this:

> Die in Expression Web® 2 eingeführte W3C-Konformität wurde wieder aufgegeben. Klickt man nur einmal auf „HTML neu formatieren“ geht die W3C-Validierung verloren.

http://www.ciao.de/Microsoft_Expression_Web_3_0__Test_8621736

It's basically saying that Expression Web 2 contained W3C conformity, but in Expression Web 3 they abandoned the effort. I hope this helps!

Comment: Is that true?  Can anybody confirm this about expression 3 being non compliant?

Thanks Jan for pointing this out.

Comment: I've seen several sources say that, however, none of them I'd trust 100%. Here's the thing though: Just because something is W3C compliant doesn't mean that all browsers render it the same or correctly. Likewise, just because it's not W3C compliant doesn't mean that browsers don't render it correctly. If you ask me, I doubt that any program (or anybody) can really cater to ALL browsers in ALL versions. If you focus on the major ones, that's a different story. I'm guessing it depends on how fancy you get and how the program chooses to describe the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a web expert. Actually I hate HTML with every fiber of my being. But I don't really think the question, as phrased in the title, has any meaning. Semantic HTML is all about context. Expression Web may or may not create *valid* HTML or XHTML that works across browsers but [semantically correct HTML](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/semantic-html/) is about using the tags where appropriate. Something Expression can't do for you.

Some very basic examples would be using a `<code>` tag for code snippets instead of `<pre>` tags, `<blockquote>` to quote someone else's words, and `<cite>` to denote a citation on an article. Expression Web will create both tags but its up to you to choose the right one.